# htaccess redirect 301 pro.php to index.php for many directories

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have this htaccess code which works fine to redirect all pro.php requests to index.php:

```
Redirect 301 /de/pro.php /de/index.php 
Redirect 301 /en/pro.php /en/index.php 
Redirect 301 /fr/pro.php /fr/index.php
```

BUT, is there an elegant possibility with just one line of code for manyfold directories /de /en /fr /.. ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use RedirectMatch :

```
RedirectMatch ^/(.+)/((?!index).+)\.php$ /$1/index.php
```

Comment: you could also hardcode your directories in the first expression: ^/(.+)/ ->^/fr|en|ru|tm/ ->list all you have to be safe